# Tool/Software for creating websites

Tags: web, gui-builder

My task is very simple. I want a tool/Software where you can create a website without big knowledge in html/css.

I know there are many out there in the internet and just searching for it results in more than 100 solutions but I don't know which of them are good, bad or perfect. I know about wordpress but that would be a total overkill for a one page website without any user interaction. I also don't need all that management of wordpress. A tool that just outputs a html file with additional css/js files will be perfect.

Wich website builder should I use?

Comment: I cannot endorse a recommendation for Word/Save As... HTML; the HTML that results is best described using language that is generally unsuitable for the StackExchange network.

Comment: What OS are you using? What's your budget? Have you tried [asking Google about WYSIWYG HTML editors](https://www.google.com/search?q=WYSIWYG+HTML+EDITOR)?

Comment: I recommend buying some cheap book about HTML, then use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to type your HTML code. This is how I am updating the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project website. And you don't even need JavaScript.... Feel free to email me (to `basile@starynkevitch.net` ....) for more. I believe you will need some knowledge about HTML and CSS.

Comment: I have tried many so called builders but I keep returning to the tool I've used to build sites for over 25 years - Notepad.  Nothing else comes close.

Answer (score 0):

For a single page static website, for someone with limited knowledge of html and css, a very good option would be blue griffon: http://www.bluegriffon.org/